# Is it possible to start all programs with admin privileges?

Tags: windows, security, user-accounts, security-warning

These days I'm having problems with "Run as Administrator" for most of my executables like Visual Studio, Command Prompt and sometimes even Notepad. It started with Visual Studio having problems copying files to the bin directory, then I couldn't save some files in Notepad. But when I start an executable with admin privileges, there are no errors.

What is going on? I'm aware of the setting shown below. Until a few days ago I didn't have those problems. Is it a "feature" of a Windows update?

[image]

There is no domain policy applied for us.

Is there any way to execute all programs as System administrator? If possible while getting rid of the "guard" symbol everywhere.

Comment: Running all programs as system administrator (and disabling User Account Control) is not a good policy for various security and stability reasons. It is better to try and understand why the programs started to ask for administrative privileges and if there is something to fix. For example, where is the `bin` directory that you are trying to write to with Visual studio? Where are the files that you are trying to edit with notepad? Does notepad require administrative privileges to edit a file on the Desktop?

Comment: Ok, i.e. There is a TNSNames.Ora file in oracle installation directory, I can edit it anyway but when I try to save it I must be an administrator. Do you think this software installed under administrator privilege, this cause that ? I don't understand.

Comment: I'm in a domain I can't start my pc as administrator. Do not know the computer pass. My idea is that; if I can do something when I just clicking run-as-admin. it means the computer knows I'm admin :) In linux it is sudo now in in windows Run as admin. , I think this policy not directly related with securing from viruses or bad programs just saving machine settings and self control. But I do not want this settings, b'cause I know what I'm doing.

Comment: If the oracle installation directory is under `C:\Program Files` then it is write protected for standard users and it requires administrator privileges to be modified. You can see the security settings for a file or folder under the security settings of the Properties window. if you need to modify that file frequently, you can modify the permissions of that file, or ask the domain administrators to do so if you can't do that.

Comment: By the way, the "run as administator" command (as well as `sudo` in Linux) is all about security. If an important file can be accessed by any program that is run on a computer it is exposed to undesired manipulations. If you run a program that doesn't require administrator privileges you are sure that it won't harm the main system components as it doesn't have write permissions for the system core locations.

Comment: Didnt you have to supply a password to run as whatever Admin your using run-as for?  I don't know what I am doing :-) And I found out that even as "power user" I can't make it 3min in the system before I am using run-as again, or just switching back to Admin. on XP or 7. I remember all the times people said "just use run-as", sure for every 3rd action :-(

Comment: You shouldn't have to run Visual Studio as an administrator.  Visual Studio already is designed to elevate its privilages anyways when its required.  The solution to the Oracle installaton problem is to move the installation directory to a non-protected directory.

Comment: @Ramhound  here is the oracle directory it is not a read only file D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
 When I double click on the file and put a letter in it I can't save it. For VS2010 I didn't faced of something like that before. The directory directly located on C:\WorkingGitDirectory\ and \bin directory is in my ignore liston  git

Comment: @Psycogeek :) Very good nick :) The only user is me. I always login my pc using my pass and there is no password validation something exist for my Mac. This really make me annoyed. Because sometimes I don't understand what is going on.I try restart,run as admin what is more... Thank you all of you commentators !

Comment: You should check the permissions of the `C:\WorkingGitDirectory\` and `D:\oracle\product\...` folder and modify them so that the group Users  has complete control over them. Also make sure that your user is the owner of the folders in the Advanced windows.

Comment: Yeah! You are right. I think there is no way of getting login as a Real-Administrator.